# Accessing Parameter from Dynamic Route in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am new to Next.js, and setting up my routing mechanism according to [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) by arranging file structuring as :
`pages/questions/[id].js`

I would like to know if there is cool/easier way to get matched `id` on my page; like in React Router (`match.params.id`). I don't want to parse `window.location.pathname` as my first option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, It was just in beginning of the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes), my bad i did't read :

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { pid } = router.query

  return <p>Post: {pid}</p>
}

export default Post
```